# Limsup and liminf of a set

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limsup-and-liminf

Let E $\subset$ $\mathbb R$ and t $\in \mathbb R$

Define $E + t = \{ x + t \mid x \in E\}$

Pick a sequence $t_n$ > 0 and $t_n \to $ 0 strictly decrasing and define:

$E_n$ = E + $t_n$

Show that if E = (-$\infty$,0) then lim $E_n$ exists and is equal to (-$\infty$,0]

My question is: How may I show the existence of the limit by computing the liminf and limsup?

1. I applied the translation, in order to work on the set (-$\infty$, $t_n$)
2. Just by drawing a graph is easy to show that the limit is (-$\infty$,0] and the zero is also included since picking a x < $t_n$ and $t_n$ goes to 0, so x will be $\le$ zero.
3. If I would like to show it by computing lim inf and lim sup, my procedure was:
   Liminf $\rightarrow$ If I pick x $\in$ (-$\infty$,0] it will be in there in all but finitely many times but also for every n, so i basically showed even the limsup.
   To be sure about the limsup, if I'd pick a x $\in$ (0,$\infty$) it will be inside this interval only for a finite number of n, so the limsup would be empty and even the liminf, so I would find a contradiction.

Is the whole reasoning correct or there is anything missing?

Another question is on how I could find similar exercise to this, about lim, liminf and limsup of intervals and translation of this kind.

Thank you!

Comment: You can use *\mathbb* MathJax police for $\mathbb R, \mathbb C$… $\Re$ means the real part of a complex number.

Comment: There is no contradiction as $(-\infty,0] \cap (0,\infty)=\emptyset.$

Comment: "..for every n so I basically showed even the limsup..." What do you mean? We always have $\liminf A_n\subseteq\limsup A_n$.

Comment: "so the limsup would be empty". That is not a correct conclusion. The correct conclusion is: so $x$ is not an element of the limsup.

Comment: I allowed myself to edit your question as there was an error in the definition of $E+t$.

Comment: Thanks. When I say "for every n so I basically showed even the limsup", i mean that for a certain point x will always be in the interval, so it will infinitely often be in the interval and also in that limsup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(A_n)_n$ is a sequence of sets then it has a limit iff $\limsup A_n=\liminf A_n$.

I general we have: $$\liminf A_n\subseteq\limsup A_n\tag0$$ so for proving that the sequence has a limit it is enough to show that $\limsup A_n\subseteq\liminf A_n$.

In this answer I provide a more general setup that might be useful for similar exercises.

---

Proving that $\lim A_n$ exists with $S=\lim A_n$ actually boils down to proving that:$$\limsup A_n\subseteq S\subseteq\liminf A_n\tag1$$
Combining $(1)$ and $(0)$ we find immediately that:$$\limsup A_n= S=\liminf A_n\tag2$$
Further in some situations it might be handsome to make use of:$$\limsup A_n\subseteq S\iff S^c\subseteq\liminf A_n^c\tag3$$which is justified by the generally true statement $(\limsup A_n)^c=\liminf A_n^c$.

So it is enough to prove that:

- For every $s\in S$ some $n_0$ exists such that $x\in A_n$ for every $n\geq n_0$.
- For every $s\notin S$ some $n_0$ exists such that $x\in A_n^c$ for every $n\geq n_0$.

Applying that in the described situation it appears to be enough to prove that:

- For every $x\leq0$ some $n_0$ exists such that $x\in E+t_n=(-\infty,t_n)$ for every $n\geq n_0$.
- For every $x>0$ some $n_0$ exists such that $x\in (E+t_n)^c=[t_n,\infty)$ for every $n\geq n_0$.

Both statements are evidently true. In the first bullet we can just take $n_0=1$ and in the second it is used that $t_n\to0$ strictly decreasing.

Comment: So basically you are saying: To show that the lim supAn $\subseteq$ S, I'm only required to show that  Sc  $\subseteq$ lim inf $\A_c$ ? So the the complement of S is (0,$\infty$) and it has to be contained in the same, since the lim inf of the complement of An is (0,$\infty$),  which is trivial. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If $t_n\downarrow0$ then $\liminf(t_n,\infty)=(0,\infty)$.

Comment: So, just to be clear, my proof was by contradiction and was it correct? Yours, instead, is a direct way to proof it. Correct?

Comment: There was things unclear for me in your proof (see my comments on it) so it is hard to judge whether it is correct.

Comment: Ok, clear. Do you have any books or sources where I can find similar excercises?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help you on this. Maybe [here](http://theanalysisofdata.com/probability/A/A.pdf) on A.4.

Answer (score 2):

So suppose that $E=(-\infty, 0)$. As $\{t_n\}$ is positive decreasing, for any $N \in \mathbb N$, you have $E_N=(-\infty,t_N)$ and

$$\bigcup_{n \ge N} E_n = E_N$$ and therefore

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} E_n = \limsup E_n =\bigcap_{N \in \mathbb N} \bigcup_{n \ge N} E_N = (-\infty ,0]$$

If you use $\liminf$, then just notice that for any $N \in \mathbb N$

$$\bigcap_{n \ge N} E_n =(-\infty,0]$$ and

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} E_n = \liminf E_n =\bigcup_{N \in \mathbb N} \bigcap_{n \ge N} E_N = (-\infty ,0]$$

Comment: Everything's clear but how would you proof that the 0 is included? I do not understand this part in your solution.

Comment: Because $0$ belongs to all $(-\infty, t_n) = E_n$. Hence to their intersection.

Comment: Ok, clear! Thank you! Do you have any books or sources where I can find similar excercises?

Comment: [This Google query may help](https://www.google.com/search?q=limsup+and+liminf+of+sets+examples+pdf&rlz=1C9BKJA_enFR708FR709&hl=fr&sxsrf=ALiCzsauvyT4qhB8dUBhzrz-vCK46QcvGQ%3A1666715430758&ei=Jg9YY4_lLY2DlwSeionABg&oq=limsup+and+liminf+of+sets+examples+pdf&gs_lcp=ChNtb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXdpei1zZXJwEAMyCAgAEKIEEIsDMggIABCiBBCLAzIICAAQogQQiwM6CggAEEcQ1gQQsAM6BggAEBYQHjoFCCEQoAFKBAhBGABQnRJYuR1gwiVoAnAAeACAAccDiAHfCJIBBzAuNC40LTGYAQCgAQHIAQi4AQHAAQE&sclient=mobile-gws-wiz-serp). With in particular [that document](https://plbailey79.github.io/portal/harc/z18/Real/TRealx34_AlgebrasOfSets.pdf).